Cucumber - Js load json data for examples for request
Feature: Api test for Login user and get token
Scenario Outline: Auth login get token
Given A login 
When I send the POST request to /auth/login
Then I get response statusCode 200
Then I get response token as string
When I send the current user GET request to /auth/me
Then I get the current user response statusCode 200
Then I get response of current user
Given A refresh 
When I send the refresh auth session POST request to /auth/refresh
Then I get the refresh auth session response statusCode 200
Then I get response of refresh auth session data with token
Examples: 
  | request                                          | refreshRequest         |
  | {"username": "kminchelle","password": "0lelplR"} | {"expiresInMins": 30 } |

I want read request data from a json file like
Examples:
| read("data/data.json") |
Is there any proper way to load the data

You can do this with Handlebars!
The handlebars library can be installed
const Handlebars = require('handlebars');

/**
 * Registers handlebars helpers with the given handlebars object.
 * @param {object} hbs The handlebars object.
 * @returns {object} The handlebars object.
 */
function registerHelpers(hbs) {
    // Data Format Helpers

    // Converts JSON object to a string.
    hbs.registerHelper('json', context => JSON.stringify(context));
}


// this is where we initialize the common helper functions with handlebars.
registerHelpers(Handlebars);

Reference data from JSON files
Place your JSON files in the ./data folder in your project. You can then reference them by name.
Given a file called myfile.json which contains { "value": 1, "message": "my message" }:

{{data.myfile.value}} - outputs 1
{{data.myfile.message}} - outputs my message

Data Format Helpers
If you want to output a value as a JSON object, use the json handlebars helper with the triple-braces:
{{{json data.myfile}}} - outputs the full json object as a string
Examples: 
  | request                                  |  
  | {{json data.events.RequestBody}}         | 


processMessage(filepath, context) {
     return Handlebars.compile(filepath);
}

const fileContents = processMessage(request, [context]);

return JSON.parse(fileContents );

